# When are the extensions $L(S)/K$ and $L(S)/L$ totally ramified?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, galois-extensions

Let $K$ be a finite extension of the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let us consider the polynomial ring $R=K[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ in $n$-variables and $f_1, f_2, \cdots, f_m \in K[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$.

Consider a finite extension $L$ of $K$ and consider the following zero set:
$$S=\{f_i(x_1, \cdots, x_n)=0, \ i=1,\cdots,m \},$$
where each $f_i \in L[x_1,x_2, \cdots , x_n]$. Then, clearly every element in $S$ is a point in an affine $n$-space over $L$. So the *coordinates of each points* in $S$ generate a field extension. i.e., conisder the field extension $L(S)$ obtained *adjoining the coordinates of each solutions* in $S$.

**Questions:**

$(1)$ Is (or When) the extension $L(S)/K$ Galois ?

$(2)$ Is (or When) the extension $L(S)/L$ Galois ?

$(3)$ When are the above two extensions totally ramified ?

$$-----------$$
$(1)$ If we assume $L$ is an **unramified extension** of $K$, then $L/K$ is Galois extension. Now $L(S)$ is the algebraic extension of $L$ because its elements are algebraic over $L$. Thus $L(S)/L$ is also Galois extension. Hence $L(S)/K$ is Galois extension.

Am I correct ?

What about the other two questions ?

Any discussion please

Comment: I might do that even though it should really be your job. By the way, at first your $f_i$ are in $K[x_1,..., x_n]$ and later they are in $L[x_1, ..., x_n]$. Of course the latter implies the former but not the other way around. So what is it? -- Also, you just write that $L$ is "an" (=arbitrary?) extension of $K$. Would it not make sense to have it finite, or at least algebraic?

Comment: Ah, I am sorry, I missed that you adjoin *all* roots of the polynomials, i.e. we have splitting fields here in the single-variable case. So (2) is true for $n=1$ for sure and it seems plausible for higher $n$ as well. (1) is more delicate, even in the single variable case I don't think that there is an easy criterion about $L(S)\vert K$ being Galois even if we know $L(S)\vert L$ is Galois by (2). I don't think "$L\vert K$ Galois" suffices, or even "$L\vert K $ unramified", although this of course does if $L(S)\vert L$ is unramified.

Comment: Regarding (3), given a tower of extensions $E\vert L \vert K$, a necessary and sufficient criterion for $E\vert K$ to be totally ramified is that $E\vert L$ and $L\vert K$ are totally ramified.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, Thanks. Yes $L$ is a finite extension of $K$. I should have mention it. Second, I am adjoining the `coordinates`  $x_i$ of the solutions of the form $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ i.e., $L(S)=\bigcup_{f_i(a_i, \cdots,a_n)=0}L(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$. So each coordinates $a_i$ would be roots of some single-variable polynomial with coeffficients in $L$. So if we can show that $L(S)=L(a)$, where $a$ is a root of an Eisenstein polynomial, then $L(S)/L$ is totally ramified. But how to show that $L(S)$ is generated by roots of Eisenstein polynomial ?